# Python working with bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to do a bit operation, and need some help:

I have a word of 16 bit and want to split it into two, reverse each and then join them again.

Example if i have 0b11000011

First I divide it into 0b1100 and 0b0011

Then i reverse both getting 0b0011 and 0b1100

And finally rejoin them getting 0b00111100

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def rev(n):
    res = 0
    mask = 0x01
    while mask <= 0x80:
        res <<= 1
        res |= bool(n & mask)
        mask <<= 1

    return res

x = 0b1100000110000011
x = (rev(x >> 8) << 8) | rev(x & 0xFF)
print bin(x) # 0b1000001111000001
```

Note that the method above operates on words, not bytes as example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

here are some basic operations you can try, and you can concatenate results  after splitting your string in two and reversing it

```
a = "0b11000011"  #make a string 

b = a[:6]         #get first 5 chars

c = a[::-1]       # invert the string
```